# Как проверить json файл на существование всех ключей и при необходимости добавить нужный(java)?

Tags: java, json

Пытаюсь более детально обработать ошибки синтаксиса `JSON`. Нужно чтобы при считывании файла производилась валидация на наличие определенных полей. В случае наличия таких ошибок пользователь должен выбрать:

- указать значение
- пропустить этот объект и загрузить оставшиеся объекты из файла в коллекцию.

Допустим, мы удалили из файла поле `name` (т.е. полностью `"name": "P3111"`). И надо чтобы программа выдавала `У вас в одном из объектов ошибка поля name. Xотите его дописать, либо пропустить загрузку этого объекта? (true/false)`
Мой метод `reader` (загрузчик `JSON`). Под полем `name` я подразумеваю именно имя группы.

```
/**
 * Чтение коллекции из файла
 *
 * @return коллекция, которая была считана из файла
 */
public PriorityQueue<StudyGroup> readCollection() {
    if (file!= null) {
        if (file.exists() & !file.canRead()) {
            System.out.println("\u001B[37m" + "\u001B[31m" + "Недостаточно прав для чтения данных из файла. Добавьте права на чтение и запустите программу вновь" + "\u001B[31m" + "\u001B[37m");
            System.exit(0);
        }
        try (FileReader fileScanner= new FileReader(file)) {
            BufferedInputStream reader= new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream((file)));
            Type collectionType = new TypeToken<PriorityQueue<StudyGroup>>(){}.getType();
            PriorityQueue<StudyGroup> collection = gson.fromJson(fileScanner, collectionType);
            reader.readAllBytes();
            System.out.println("\u001B[37m" + "\u001B[33m" + "Коллекция успешно загружена!" + "\u001B[33m" + "\u001B[37m");
            if (collection == null) return new PriorityQueue<>();
            return collection;
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            System.err.println("Файл с таким именем не найден :(");

        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.err.println("Ошибка ввода-вывода");

        } catch (JsonSyntaxException e) {
            System.err.println("Формат файла не удовлетворяет условию");
        }
        catch (RuntimeException e){
            Messages.normalMessageOutput("\u001B[37m" + "\u001B[33m"+"Файл написан с ошибкой, перепроверьте файл и запустите программу снова"+ "\u001B[33m" + "\u001B[37m");
        }
    } else
        System.out.println("\u001B[37m" + "\u001B[31m" + "Системная переменная с загрузочным файлом не найдена!" + "\u001B[31m" + "\u001B[37m");
    return new PriorityQueue<>();
}
```

`JSON` файл:

```
[
  {
    "id": 4229754249302793000,
    "name": "P3111",
    "coordinates": {
      "x": 32,
      "y": -360
    },
    "creationDate": {
      "date": {
        "year": 2021,
        "month": 4,
        "day": 27
      },
      "time": {
        "hour": 10,
        "minute": 41,
        "second": 15,
        "nano": 506122400
      }
    },
    "studentsCount": 32,
    "expelledStudents": 5,
    "formOfEducation": "DISTANCE_EDUCATION",
    "semesterEnum": "FIRST",
    "groupAdmin": {
      "name": "Маша",
      "passportID": "123",
      "eyeColor": "BLACK",
      "hairColor": "BLACK",
      "nationality": "USA"
    }
  },
  {
    "id": 5576486070722418000,
    "name": "P3111",
    "coordinates": {
      "x": 32,
      "y": -360
    },
    "creationDate": {
      "date": {
        "year": 2021,
        "month": 4,
        "day": 27
      },
      "time": {
        "hour": 10,
        "minute": 41,
        "second": 24,
        "nano": 974652600
      }
    },
    "studentsCount": 32,
    "expelledStudents": 5,
    "formOfEducation": "DISTANCE_EDUCATION",
    "semesterEnum": "FIRST",
    "groupAdmin": {
      "name": "Маша",
      "passportID": "123",
      "eyeColor": "BLACK",
      "hairColor": "BLACK",
      "nationality": "USA"
    }
  }
]
```

Comment: это обычная валидация, проводится она не на уровне джейсона , а на уровне объекта. т.е. вы парсите джейсон как есть (на этом уровне можно обработать только ошибки самого джейсона, к примеру, незакрытые кавычки) , а потом на уровне полученного объекта , используя стандартные средства валидации , провенряете данные

Comment: Да, но вот только если я из json  удалю полностью ключ и его значение то вылетит Runtime Exception и мне надо обработать это в catch  чтобы при такой ситуации было возможно восполнить этот ключ и его значение

Answer (score 1):

Предлагаю Вам посмотреть в сторону [JSON Schema](https://json-schema.org/). Можно по Вашим данным сгенерировать схему, например, воспользовавшись одним из [генераторов](https://json-schema.org/implementations.html#schema-generators).

Вот пример получившейся схемы по Вашим данным (использвался онлайн генератор [quicktype.io](https://app.quicktype.io/#l=schema)):

```
{
    "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-06/schema#",
    "type": "array",
    "items": {
        "$ref": "#/definitions/WelcomeElement"
    },
    "definitions": {
        "WelcomeElement": {
            "type": "object",
            "additionalProperties": false,
            "properties": {
                "id": {
                    "type": "number"
                },
                "name": {
                    "type": "string"
                },
                "coordinates": {
                    "$ref": "#/definitions/Coordinates"
                },
                "creationDate": {
                    "$ref": "#/definitions/CreationDate"
                },
                "studentsCount": {
                    "type": "integer"
                },
                "expelledStudents": {
                    "type": "integer"
                },
                "formOfEducation": {
                    "type": "string"
                },
                "semesterEnum": {
                    "type": "string"
                },
                "groupAdmin": {
                    "$ref": "#/definitions/GroupAdmin"
                }
            },
            "required": [
                "coordinates",
                "creationDate",
                "expelledStudents",
                "formOfEducation",
                "groupAdmin",
                "id",
                "name",
                "semesterEnum",
                "studentsCount"
            ],
            "title": "WelcomeElement"
        },
        "Coordinates": {
            "type": "object",
            "additionalProperties": false,
            "properties": {
                "x": {
                    "type": "integer"
                },
                "y": {
                    "type": "integer"
                }
            },
            "required": [
                "x",
                "y"
            ],
            "title": "Coordinates"
        },
        "CreationDate": {
            "type": "object",
            "additionalProperties": false,
            "properties": {
                "date": {
                    "$ref": "#/definitions/Date"
                },
                "time": {
                    "$ref": "#/definitions/Time"
                }
            },
            "required": [
                "date",
                "time"
            ],
            "title": "CreationDate"
        },
        "Date": {
            "type": "object",
            "additionalProperties": false,
            "properties": {
                "year": {
                    "type": "integer"
                },
                "month": {
                    "type": "integer"
                },
                "day": {
                    "type": "integer"
                }
            },
            "required": [
                "day",
                "month",
                "year"
            ],
            "title": "Date"
        },
        "Time": {
            "type": "object",
            "additionalProperties": false,
            "properties": {
                "hour": {
                    "type": "integer"
                },
                "minute": {
                    "type": "integer"
                },
                "second": {
                    "type": "integer"
                },
                "nano": {
                    "type": "integer"
                }
            },
            "required": [
                "hour",
                "minute",
                "nano",
                "second"
            ],
            "title": "Time"
        },
        "GroupAdmin": {
            "type": "object",
            "additionalProperties": false,
            "properties": {
                "name": {
                    "type": "string"
                },
                "passportID": {
                    "type": "string",
                    "format": "integer"
                },
                "eyeColor": {
                    "type": "string"
                },
                "hairColor": {
                    "type": "string"
                },
                "nationality": {
                    "type": "string"
                }
            },
            "required": [
                "eyeColor",
                "hairColor",
                "name",
                "nationality",
                "passportID"
            ],
            "title": "GroupAdmin"
        }
    }
}
```

Далее необходимо выбрать и подключить одну из реализаций [валидаторов](https://json-schema.org/implementations.html#validator-java), наиболее подходящую для Ваших нужд.